# How to know regarding entity structure and name without self description of a REST service

Tags: rest

I have read a lot that a REST service don't require self description. I am providing a simple example. Say, I want to update a "customer" object. As a consumer of the REST service, how I can send information for updating without knowing the exact "Customer" class name (it could be "cust" or something else) and its property. I know there is WADL which self describe a REST service. But as per REST specification there is no need of this. I cannot understand, how it is possible for a consumer to know the entity name and properties wiThout self description(without manual intervention). Could anybody help me out to clear my concept on this?

Comment: You will definitely want to provide documentation to the consumers, covering what endpoints you provide and their inputs/outputs. Without it they have no idea really how to use your service. Unlike SOAP services that require a WSDL, REST services do not *require* a WADL, and in fact you can provide documentation in any manner you like (HTML pages, PDF, interactive test bed, JavaDoc etc etc).

Answer (score 0):

Not needed != not useful

The idea is you can construct restful resouce requests without entity descriptions unlike say soap which requires you to consume a wsdl.

Does this mean a descriptor wouldn't be useful in some cases? No.

Also, your services don't necessarily have to map to classes and properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please clarify me few points:                              "Also, your services don't necessarily have to map to classes and properties" is there any other way to represent entities for a service without classes and properties?

Comment: @user1672097 sure, your resource may expose a an aggregate of other classes or you may wish to hide, trasform, rename, etc... properties.